# What does this vector space mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Here is a quote from pages 4 and 5 of https://aetos.it.teithe.gr/~gouliana/en/2017-polynomials.pdf

> As it is well known from nonlinear algebra, the structure of a typical nonlinear algebraic system of $n$ equations with $n$ unknowns has the form
>   $$f_1(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)=0$$
>   $$f_2(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)=0$$
>   $$\cdots$$
>   $$f_n(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)=0$$
>   Or using vector notation, $F(x)=0$ where
>   $$F=(f_1, f_2, ..., f_n)^T$$
>   is a vector of non-linear functions $f_i(x)=f_i(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$
>   each being defined in the vector space
>   $$\Omega=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{\{\alpha_i, \beta_i\} \subset \text{R}^n}$$
>   of all real valued and continuous functions.

My question is what does the above vector space mean?

Comment: I assume that $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ is supposed to represent an interval.  Aren't there some kind of brackets around it?  But in any event, this isn't a vector space with the usual definition of addition.  If the source says it's a vector space, it must define what addition and scalar multiplication mean.

Comment: What you've written makes no sense to me. I can't tell what things are in $\Omega$. Please edit the question to include more context for the source of the problem.

Comment: As written, it is not clear what that means

Comment: Who knows? ${}{}$

Comment: The braces needed to be escaped so that they showed up in the formatted output.  Still, I don't know what kind of interval that is supposed to represent.  What does the source say about it? Or is perhaps supposed to be $(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$ or  $[\alpha_i,\beta_i]?$

Comment: The source says $\{\alpha_i, \beta_i\}$

Comment: I edited the question and added a quote from the paper.

Comment: Seems like a mistake. Overall, the text does not impress me as a hight-quality text, maybe you should find a better textbook.

Comment: Doesn't the text say anything about what are $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$?

Comment: A bit later $\beta_i$ is mentioned as a constant in the function $f_i$ but $\alpha_i$ is not mentioned.

Comment: It is poor notation on the text, I understand why you are confused. If I had to guess and I am the vector space is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ so I think this is a bounded polytope. If all $\alpha_i$ and $\beta _i$ are the same this would be a $n$-dim square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the context, he means that each of the coordinate functions $f_i$ is defined and continuous on  $$\Omega=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{[\alpha_i, \beta_i] \subset \text{R}^n}$$

The vector space referred to is the vector of space of such functions.

To put it another way, $$
\Omega=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)|\alpha_i\leq x_i\leq\beta_i, i=1,2,\dots,n\}
$$

This isn't what the paper *says*, but I feel pretty sure that's what it means.  I'm not certain, though, about the inequalities.  Perhaps they are meant to be strict.